# Estimating an integral under strong regularity conditions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Under the assumption that $g_n$ are nonnegative bounded functions $\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ such that for all $n$:  $\int_\mathbf{R} g_n = S$, and $g_n \to 0$ uniformly on any compact set $K \subset \mathbf{R}_{\neq 0}$, I'm trying to show that the following statement holds

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, There is some $N$ such that $\left| \int_\mathbf{R} g_n f - S f(0)\right| < \epsilon$ when $n > N$.

In the statement above $f$ is rapidly decreasing (aka, [Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space)). Any hints on getting an estimate?

Comment: Perhaps you want some condition like "all the $g_n$ are supported inside some single compact set"?  Otherwise it's not true as stated.

Answer (score 1):

That is not true. You probably think that your conditions force the mass to be shifted to the origin, but it can as well be shifted to infinity. Here is an example:

Let $g_n=1_{[n,n+1]}$. Clearly, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g_n=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g_n\to 0$ uniformly on compact sets. However, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f g_n\to 0$ for all Schwartz functions $f$ (or indeed all $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$) by dominated convergence. Indeed, this will always happen if the sequence $(g_n)$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you just gave a counter example to https://imgur.com/a/F4daM ? Note that $\mathcal{S}'$ denotes the dual of scwhartz: tempered distribution.

Comment: Yes, the implied statement in the link is not true (unless the author uses some weird topology on $\mathcal{S}'$).